# Python Cartesian Product

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)

I'm trying to figure out some logic that I just can't wrap my head around. Say I have the following data structure:

```
letters = (
    ('b','c'),
    ('a','e','ee'),
    ('d','f'),
    ('e','y'),
)
```

How would I iterate through this to get every possible string combination:

```
bade
cade
bede
cede
beede
ceede
bafe
cafe
befe
cefe
beefe
ceefe
bady
cady
bedy
cedy
beedy
ceedy
bafy
cafy
befy
cefy
beefy
ceefy
```

Comment: You are looking for the cartesian product: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: @Dustin, I don't think what you want is the cartesian product, but the combinations of those strings. Keep in mind that the cartesian product is an operation between two sets `A` and `B` in which `AxB = {(a, b): a ∈ A and b ∈ B}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for l in itertools.product(*letters):
    print ''.join(l)
```

Comment: What is the use of `*` before letters? What does it do?

Comment: Argument unpacking: *[a, b, c] is a, b, c